# Showing $\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos20^\circ}{1+\cos40^\circ}} =\frac{\cos80^\circ}{\cos20^\circ}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, problem-solving

**Here is a problem:**

[image]

**Here is (the short version of) the question:**

I did this problem using the Cosine Rule on $\triangle PQU$ and $\triangle PTU$. This gave me an answer of
$$\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos20^\circ}{1+\cos40^\circ}} \tag{1}$$ The given answer is, however: $$\frac{\cos80^\circ}{\cos20^\circ} \tag{2}$$ Both give the **same numerical answer** when put into a calculator.

> I was wondering whether it is possible to convert/manipulate $(1)$ into $(2)$. Or, is using the Cosine Rule just not acceptable here, to get the "correct" answer?

Many thanks.

---

If you don't understand how I got my answer or how they got theirs, I can attach both pieces of working. Hopefully it is clear though! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the identities $1-\cos x=2\sin^2x/2$ and $1+\cos x=2\cos^2x/2$ your answer becomes
$$\sqrt{\frac{2\sin^210^\circ}{2\cos^220^\circ}}=\frac{\sin10^\circ}{\cos20^\circ}=\frac{\cos80^\circ}{\cos20^\circ}$$

Comment: Thanks @ParclyTaxel - is there somewhere I could find out more about those two identities you mention? This is the first time I have come across them, so it might be useful to read up a bit about them/watch an explanatory video. Thank you.

Comment: @Rushi These are half-angle identities. You **really** need to learn them by heart.